# ¿Por qué "Vete a la mierda" muestra enfado pero "Mucha mierda" desea suerte?

Tags: uso-de-palabras, expresiones

No acabo de entender cómo la palabra *mierda* puede tener unos usos tan opuestos.

En la frase "*Vete a la mierda*" claramente se muestra enfado hacia una persona. Sin embargo, al decir "*Mucha mierda*", se le desea suerte en lo que sea que vaya a hacer en un futuro próximo.

¿Cómo es posible que se use para expresar **sentimientos tan contrarios** y **de dónde vienen estas expresiones**?

Comment: Si la expresión _mucha mierda_ es usada en España _u otros países_, la pregunta debería ser etiquetada con al menos 1 país.

Comment: @Mauricio sé que en España se utiliza, pero ni idea si en otros también

Comment: Quiero resaltar que dicha expresión se utiliza en el mundo del espectáculo, tal y como dice el [diccionario](https://dle.rae.es/?id=PDmoCWN). Nunca la he escuchado fuera de ese ámbito.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Tal y como comentas acertadamente, *mierda* es una palabra que generalmente designa cosas malas. Esto es por motivos obvios y se usa coloquialmente:

- Veta a la mierda.
- Esto es una mierda.
- ¡Mierda! Me he dejado el reloj.

Sin embargo, existe la expresión *mucha mierda* usada para desear suerte. En el magnífico blog [*Ya está el listo que todo lo sabe*](http://blogs.20minutos.es/yaestaellistoquetodolosabe/el-origen-de-la-expresion-mucha-mierda/) se describe así:

> El origen de esta expresión tiene dos versiones muy distintas y ninguna de ellas está contrastada, así que queda a criterio del lector elegir la que más le convenza.
>
> Por un lado nos encontramos quienes dicen que el origen de la expresión proviene de la época en la que las personas de clases pudientes acudían al teatro (en aquella época corrales de comedia) en sus coches de caballos. Al llegar a la puerta del recinto, mientras bajaban del coche, el animal hacía sus necesidades allí mismo, por lo que cuando estaba a punto de empezar la representación un miembro de la compañía se asomaba y miraba la cantidad de excremento depositada. Cuanta más había, más gente de dinero se encontraba entre el público; algo muy importante, porque como no se cobraba entrada, su sustento dependía del dinero que, concluida la función, los espectadores lanzasen al escenario. Los miembros de la compañía se agachaban a recoger las monedas lanzaras por el público y de ahí dicen que viene otra expresión teatral de aparente paradójico significado: «rómpete una pierna» (es decir, que tengas mucha suerte y te rompas la pierna de tantas veces que tengas que flexionarla para recoger el dinero recaudado o para saludar al público).
>
> La otra versión especula con que el origen se remonta a la Edad Media, cuando los artistas iban con sus carromatos de pueblo en pueblo. Cuando llegaban a uno, si había mucho estiércol a la entrada, podían saber si (en función de la extensión del mismo) en aquel momento había un mercado, feria u otro acto y merecía la pena detenerse para hacer su espectáculo. El deseo entonces, entre los compañeros de gremio, era que encontrasen mucha mierda en el siguiente pueblo, quedando la expresión abreviada que ha llegado a nuestros días.

Pese a no estar contrastadas, en ambos casos vemos un patrón claro: mierda -> caballos -> gente con dinero -> posible negocio. Por tanto, pese a que la *mierda* en sí no sea algo bueno, se entiende que si es de un caballo es porque su dueño lo está montando con unas cuantas monedas en el bolsillo.

Comment: Mientras leía tu respuesta iba recordando que alguien me lo había contado ya antes (la primera hipótesis) pero sí, tiene todo el sentido del mundo entonces. Gracias por las siempre buenas respuestas @fedorqui

Comment: The English wikiepedia entry for "break a leg" https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Break_a_leg also suggests that professional dancers use the French word _merde_  which is of interest as your quote also explains the phrase _rmoper una pierna_.

Comment: Qué interesante, siempre había supuesto que el origen de la expresión era, simplemente, que los artistas consideraban de mala suerte desearse buena suerte y que, por eso, se deseaban lo contrario.

Comment: Algo leí sobre lo de "rómpete una pierna" viniendo de la expresión en inglés. Porque al romperte la pierna te ponen un "cast" (escayola) pero "cast" también es reparto/papel como en una función. Así que "rómpete la pierna" sería un "ojalá consigas el papel"

Comment: Yo también escuché esa explicación de que se emplea la palabra supersticiosamente porque desear "suerte" hace que se vaya la suerte. Lo del origen francés tiene sin duda que ver porque en Argentina de hecho se desea *merde* ([merde], no [mɛʁd]).